# JAXWS runtime exception

Tags: java, web-services, jboss, jax-ws, jboss5.x

I am using JBoss 5.1.0GA and jaxws-api 2.1.1 and maven and my webservice is

```
@WebMethod
public GenericResponse getExternalSystems() throws java.rmi.RemoteException{
    return engineExternal.getExternalSystems();
}
```

The runtime exception that I get on deploy is the following:

```
Caused by: org.jboss.ws.WSException: arg0 is not a valid property on class ClassName
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getElementPropertyAccessor(JAXBContextImpl.java:971)
    at org.jboss.ws.metadata.accessor.JAXBAccessorFactory.create(JAXBAccessorFactory.java:49)
    at org.jboss.ws.metadata.umdm.EndpointMetaData.createAccessor(EndpointMetaData.java:763)
    at org.jboss.ws.metadata.umdm.EndpointMetaData.eagerInitializeAccessors(EndpointMetaData.java:697)
    at org.jboss.ws.metadata.umdm.EndpointMetaData.initializeInternal(EndpointMetaData.java:569)
    at org.jboss.ws.metadata.umdm.EndpointMetaData.eagerInitialize(EndpointMetaData.java:557)
    at org.jboss.ws.metadata.umdm.ServiceMetaData.eagerInitialize(ServiceMetaData.java:433)
    at org.jboss.ws.metadata.umdm.UnifiedMetaData.eagerInitialize(UnifiedMetaData.java:199)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.EagerInitializeDeploymentAspect.start(EagerInitializeDeploymentAspect.java:48)
    at org.jboss.webservices.integration.deployers.WSDeploymentAspectDeployer.internalDeploy(WSDeploymentAspectDeployer.java:107)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
    ... 30 more
```

I have found some solutions that use ant tasks:

http://billytee.wordpress.com/2009/09/03/jboss-jax-ws-is-not-a-valid-property-on-class/

http://www.javalinux.it/wordpress/2009/03/16/ant-171-and-package-infojava-compilation-problem-of-jax-ws-generated-classes/

But I use maven, so I can't use these solutions.
What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs when parameters are not properly annotated in the web service implementation.

Make sure that all params are annotated.
For eg:
@WebParam(name="param_name")

where param_name implies the name of the element as present in the WSDL.

Comment: The problem is that the method that gives the error has no paramenter at all. This is the most strange thing about it.